# Continuity of the intrinsic distance function $d(\mu, X) = |\mu - X - 2\pi \nu^{(X)}(\mu)|$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, continuity

The source material is the paper [Intrinsic Means on the Circle: Uniqueness, Locus and Asymptotics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.2141) by Hotz and Huckerman, pp. 3.

Namely, let $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n ~ X $ be i.i.d. r.v.s which are mappings from a probability space $(\Omega, A, \mathbb{P})$ to the interval $[-\pi, \pi)$, which represents the unit circle $S^1$. The intrinsic distance is defined for a point $\mu \in S^1$ and an outcome $X$ as $d(\mu, X) = \left| \mu - X - 2\pi\nu^{(X)}(\mu)\right|$, with $\nu^{(X)}(\mu) = \begin{cases}1 &: \mu > 0, X \in [-\pi, \mu - \pi)\\-1 &: \mu < 0, X \in (\pi + \mu, \pi)\\ 0 &: \text{else }\\
\end{cases}$.

Define the intrinsic variance as $V(\mu) = \mathbb{E}(d(\mu, X)^2)$.

The authors state that:

> Note that $V$ ..., being continuous functions on the compact $S^1$, always feature at least one global minimizer.

But how in what way is $\nu^{(X)}(\mu)$ a continuous function? If we let $X = -\pi$ and define a sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$, then for every $n \in \mathbb{N}: \nu^{(-\pi)}(a_n) = 1$. But $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$ and $\nu^{(-\pi)}(0) = 0 \neq 1$.

Comment: I don't want to parse their expression, but I think that $d(\mu, x)$ is the distance from $\mu$ to $x$ as measured on the circle. Hence it is a metric, and therefore continuous in both arguments. It's something like $d(x, y)$ is length of shortest path from $e^{ix}$ to $e^{iy}$ on the unit circle.

Comment: @Mason But if the distance is continuous in both arguments, then shouldn't $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(a_n, -\pi) = d(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n, -\pi)$? But $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(a_n, -\pi) = \left|\frac{1}{n} - 3\pi\right|$ and $d(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n, -\pi) = |-\pi|$.

Comment: No, $d(1/n, -\pi) = |1/n - \pi|$.

Comment: @Mason Ah, you are correct! I suppose that one should never work with double negatives in the evening.